# Why is 自分たち used here?

Tags: meaning, pronouns, second-person-pronouns

I was wondering why **自分たち** is used instead of, let's say **トールたち** or another personal pronoun to refer to Tohru and Co.

for context: Tohru and Co just finished performing a stage play. They managed it pull it off without help and Kobayashi is praising her.

[image: headpats are cute]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

自分たちだけで is used with the meaning of "all by yourselves".

自分で is often used in situations where you would use a reflexive pronoun in English, for example

> **自分で**できた
>   I managed (to do it) **by myself** / She managed (to do it) **by herself** / etc.

where the translation of course depends on the context.

In 自分たちだけで

- たち is added to make it plural (ourselves, yourselves, themselves) and
- だけ "only" to emphasize that whatever they did, they did without any external help — in English 自分**だけ**で could be translated as "**all** by myself/herself/..." for emphasis.